# Save back to XML file with changed element

Tags: c#, linq

I have my XML as:

```
<CONFIGURATION NAME="HDD"> 
<DECLARATION NAME="1ST_HDD_SATA">   
 <INSTANCE>     
  <PROPERTY  NAME="ControllerPosition" CHECKPOSITION="true">
   <INDEX>
    <VALUE>0</VALUE>
    <VALUE STEP="1">Std.flg</VALUE>
    <VALUE STEP="2">Sas.flg</VALUE>
    <VALUE STEP="-1">eS.flg</VALUE>`
  <CONFIGURATION NAME="HDD"> 
  <DECLARATION NAME="1ST_HDD_SATA">   
   <INSTANCE>     
   <PROPERTY NAME="ControllerPosition"  CHECKPOSITION="true">      
  <INDEX>         
  <VALUE>0</VALUE>         
  <VALUE STEP="1">Std_Ctrl.flg</VALUE> 
  <VALUE STEP="2">Sas_Card.flg</VALUE>        
  <VALUE STEP="-1">eSAS1.flg</VALUE>
  </INDEX>
  <INDEX>
  <VALUE>0</VALUE>
  </INDEX>
  </PROPERTY>   
 </INSTANCE> 
</DECLARATION> 
</CONFIGURATION>
```

Got the Values using LINQ and displayed all  elements in Textbox, only VALUE elements.

```
var hdd= from n1 in x.Elements("DECLARATION") where 1.Attribute("NAME").Value.Trim() == "1ST_HDD_SATA_Position" select n1.Elements("INSTANCE").Elements("PROPERTY").Elements("INDEX").Elements("VALUE");
```

Then Updated the textbox to include new values for VALUE Element. For example lets say I updated it to some string.

```
 foreach (IEnumerable<XElement> elList in hdd)
  foreach (XElement el in elList)
  {

    el.ReplaceNodes("string");
    el.Save(m);
  }
```

Isn't this suppose to save my xml file with the update?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "LINQ to XML- C# " and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Also, if it "doesn't work", what does it do instead of working?

Comment: Please use System.Xml instead of LInQ

Comment: To me, it kind of ruins the OOP part of it by making it like SQL

Answer (score 3):

There are many problems with your code, starting with the fact that you posted invalid XML. Assuming that your XML was like this:

```
<CONFIGURATION NAME="HDD">
  <DECLARATION NAME="1ST_HDD_SATA">
    <INSTANCE>
      <PROPERTY  NAME="ControllerPosition" CHECKPOSITION="true">
        <INDEX>
          <VALUE>0</VALUE>
          <VALUE STEP="1">Std.flg</VALUE>
          <VALUE STEP="2">Sas.flg</VALUE>
          <VALUE STEP="-1">eS.flg</VALUE>
        </INDEX>
      </PROPERTY>
    </INSTANCE>
  </DECLARATION>
</CONFIGURATION>
```

Then the following code works:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("Configuration.xml");

var hdd = from n1 in doc.Elements("CONFIGURATION").Elements("DECLARATION")
          let nameAttribute = n1.Attribute("NAME")
          where nameAttribute != null && nameAttribute.Value.Trim() == "1ST_HDD_SATA"
          select n1.Elements("INSTANCE")
                   .Elements("PROPERTY")
                   .Elements("INDEX")
                   .Elements("VALUE");
foreach (var elList in hdd)
    foreach (var el in elList)
    {
        el.ReplaceNodes("string");
    }

doc.Save("Configuration.xml");
```